# tesla charger installation 60 amp vs 50 amps cable

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, cables, electric-vehicle

I am planning to run a 60 amp wire and install Nema 14-50  with 50 amp breaker on it. That way in future if i buy a tesla wall connector, i can install the 60 amp breaker and the new receptacle on the same wiring.

what is the price difference between 60 amp and 50 amp wire. Is it too excessive?

Comment: Pricing questions are off-topic unless it's an XY question to the effect of "is there a difference?"   In this case, it is.

Comment: This question is about price, and would be better answered by contacting your local supplier

Answer (score 2):

The correct wire for both 50A and 60A circuits is 6 AWG Cu or 4 AWG Al.   That is because you are required to pull from the 60 degree C column of NEC 310.15(B)16, which says 55A, and you are allowed to "round up" to the next available breaker size.

At large sizes such as 4 AWG, there is no earthly reason to waste money on copper wire, provided that breaker, socket and any splices be rated for aluminum wire.   Certainly if you are going a long distance, and needing a size bump to reduce voltage drop, aluminum is the right stuff.

There has been a problem in the past with people (including electricians) installing 40A circuits for Tesla chargers, using 8 AWG Cu wire, and finding they must then upgrade to 6Cu or 4Al. That happens because the Tesla charger is labeled for 40A, and they're forgetting  NEC 210.20(a) which requires 125% of rating for continuous loads, and 625.40 which affirms it for EV chargers.  Don't install 8 AWG.

Comment: Unless, due to the distance, he needs to de-rate for voltage drop. We don't know the distance, i.e. "enough details"...

Answer (score 0):

Pricing questions are pointless since we don't know where you are, how you buy, or enough details about your installation to know exactly what size you need. But as a gross generalization, the difference will probably end up around 20% more for the larger wire, FWIW.

More importantly though, it will be a LOT cheaper than having to redo it later...